# Using acts_as_list on multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I have a possibly unique case where I need a model to have two differing orders depending on the model it is joined to.  Example as follows:

```
class Book
  acts_as_list :column => :genre, :scope => :genre
  acts_as_list :column => :author, :scope => :author
  belongs_to :genre
  belongs_to :author
end
```

So basically what I am trying to do is have a Book model which is part of two lists, one for the genre page it appears on, and one for the author page it appears on.

`acts_as_list` does not appear to support the use of 2 position columns as methods such as `move_to_top` does not allow you to specify which list to move to the top of.

Has anyone got any suggestions on how I could achieve this?  Right now I am thinking I will have to create a join table such as `books_genres` which has a `position` column, but I am really not too keen on that as that requires a whole load of extra tables.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I've started a bounty as I need the same solution

Comment: Unfortunately not, couldn't find a solution, wouldn't mind that bounty though!

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same feature...

Comment: Same problem, 5 years later. I'll probably use `ranked-model`.

Comment: Actually, this is now solved as of 0.7.6  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38667692/967115

Answer (score 2):

Old post but I hope this helps. This works with act_as_list 0.7.6 at least...

Add your scope in an array and use the ids as params...

```
belongs_to :website
belongs_to :page    
acts_as_list scope: [:website_id, :page_id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Acts as list not designed for multiple columns.plugin will almost rewrite if you want to use it in this way. But I think you can try do this.

```
class Book
  belongs_to :genre
  belongs_to :author
end

class GenreBook < Book
  acts_as_list :column => :genre, :scope => :genre
end

class AuthorBook < Book
  acts_as_list :column => :author, :scope => :author
end
```

not sure it does work. theoretically possible.

Comment: This works if you only need one kind of order per time you load a collection of books.

Answer (score 1):

Try out another gem called [ranked-model](https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model). It supports the case that you mentioned by specify :with_same option. I have tried it myself.

For your example, you can do:

```
class Book
    belongs_to :genre
    belongs_to :author

    ranks :within_genre,
      :with_same => :genre_id,
      :column => :genre

    ranks :within_author,
      :with_same => :author_id,
      :column => :author
end
```